# Convert MongoDB date format from strict JSON in Mule?

Tags: mongodb, mule

I have a Mule flow that's returning data from a MongoDB database. Currently the dates are being returned in the format `"lastLoginDate" : { "$date" : 1382456335880}`, but I need to return it in the format `"lastLoginDate" : { "Timestamp":"2013-10-22T15:39:07.070Z"}`. How can I accomplish this in Mule? Right now the only transformer is the Mongo-collection-to-JSON.

Comment: Why do you need to return it in an already converted-to-string form?  The value associated with $date is an epoch time (millis since 1-Jan-1970 00:00:00.000 UTC) can be used immediately used to construct a Date() object.

Comment: The JSON is being deserialized by Jackson, which apparently expects the date in the latter format. I'm wondering if a more appropriate solution would be to extend the Jackson date deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

In case You still need to convert it into the desired format, then you can use this transformation: `Timestamp: (1382456335880 / 1000) as :datetime`. The result will be: `"Timestamp": "2013-10-22T15:38:55Z"`

Notes: value is divided by 1000, because the input is in milliseconds and DataWeave requires it in seconds.